# How to set a fixed time cookie in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am using cookies to store user preferences. When users log in I want to get their preferences from the database and store them in cookies. I want to store the cookie to expire on a fixed date like this:

```
document.cookie = document.getElementById('user').value + '=' + preferences + '; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2030 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.website.com';
```

As you can see the JavaScript method sets the cookie to expire on `31-Dec-2030 23:59:59 GMT`. How can I do the same in PHP? 
One more thing the way I am storing cookie sets the cookie name to user name and the preferences are not encrypted they are stored as plain text. They don't have any sensitive information though. Is it safe to use cookies this way?

Answer (score 0):

Use php `strtotime()`

```
setcookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value", strtotime('2030-31-12 23:59:59 GMT'));
```

Comment: What about the time `23:59:59 GMT`?

Comment: Does GMT have no effect?

Comment: Oh, you can add GMT on the end @SujataHulsurkar

Comment: the cookie is expiring at the end of session.

Answer (score 0):

Use php `time()`

```
setcookie("cookiename", 'cookievalue', strtotime('2030-31-12 23:59:59 GMT'));
```

Comment: This will not set the cookie to expire on `31-Dec-2030 23:59:59 GMT`